# barode reader в режиме эмуляции клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, barcode

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    timepress = new Date();
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    timeup = new Date();
    var sub = timeup - timepress;   
    console.log(sub);
    if (sub > 14) {
        BarCode = "";
    }   

}, false);
```

Задача стоит в том, чтобы понимать где ввод с клавиатуры в где с ридера.
Проблема: Разница между событиями `keyup`  и `keydown` нам известна, но я не могу определить оптимальный параметр для сравнение с переменной `sub`, так как ридеры могут быть беспроводные и разница во времени между этими событиями может быть больше чем у быстрых [клавиатур](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016QO64FI).[image: введите сюда описание изображения] .

Как выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: Причём тут отклик? Как я понял, вы пытаетесь отличить клавиатурный ввод и ввода с ридера по скорости "нажимания". То есть дело не в отклике клавиатуры, а в скорости человеческих пальцев.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56853048/keyup-event-handler-skips-first-event - аналогичный вопрос.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290898/detect-when-input-box-filled-by-keyboard-and-when-by-barcode-scanner/15354814#15354814 - Решение